# Can't assign set to variable python

Tags: python, variables, opencv, set, variable-assignment

Hi I was wondering if this was possible at all, since I tried it but my variable was always empty. In my project, I'm tracking a static object and a laser pointer via a PiCamera on my raspberry pi, and I calculate the centroids of their contours as `(smallx,smally)` and `(small2x,small2y)` respectively.

I use the difference between their coordinates to see if the pointer should go up, down, left, or right in order to meet the 1st static object. After that, it'll choose a direction betweeen 1 through 4 to move, because my direction controls aren't perfectly on an x-y axis and are slanted.

I left the controls and the contour finding out from here and shortened my total code just so that you wouldn't be met with a giant pile of slop to sort through.

EDIT: I' don't think with my understanding I could provide something runnable without posting a couple hundred lines and my little device, but I'll boil it down and post the exact portion of my code where this is relevant. Running Python 2.7.3, using opencv2.4.10

Code:

```
#import libraries like picamera and opencv
#set empty variables like:
up = down = left = right = set()
smallx = smally = small2x = small2y = 0
#etc etc

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    with picamera.array.PiRGBArray(camera) as rawCapture:

    #Calibrate my controls with the camera. updates the up, down, left, and right sets.


with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    with picamera.array.PiRGBArray(camera) as rawCapture:

    # Take pictures, threshold them, find contours, append their arrays to list

    if len(cnts)>0:     #If any objects were identified
            contm = sorted(smalList, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
            smallest = cnts[smalList[0][0]]           #**Take smallest object(my static object)**

            smallM = cv2.moments(smallest)                      
            smallx = int(smallM['m10']/smallM['m00'])  #**Calculate xcoord**   
            smally = int(smallM['m01']/smallM['m00'])  #**Calculate ycoord**

            cv2.line(frame, (smallx,smally), (smallx,smally), 1, 8,0) #Draws centroid

            # print(len(cnts))

            if len(cnts)==2:        #If only 2 objects were identified
                smallester = cnts[smalList[1][0]]      #** Take pointer object **
                small2 = cv2.moments(smallester)                        
                small2x = int(small2['m10']/small2['m00']) #**Calculate xcoord**
                small2y = int(small2['m01']/small2['m00']) #**Calculate ycoord**

                x = small2x - smallx
                y = small2y - smally

                print x #These prints return a value
                print y


                if x < 0:                       #Difference = Pointer - Object
                    s1 = right

                if x >0:
                    s1 = left

                if y < 0:
                    s2 = down
                if y >0:
                    s2 = up
                print s1, s2                  #set([]),set([])
                print up,down,left,right      #set([1,2]),set([3,4]),set([1,4]),set([2,3])

                selecty = s1&s2               #set([])


    #Tell the pointer where to go
```

Should I even be using sets?

Comment: If `s1` and `s2` are always still `0`, then none of your `if` conditions is evaluating true-y. From what you've posted, we cannot tell you why. But it is certainly possible to assign a set, *it those lines are reached*.

Comment: `small2x,smallx = 5,3`

Comment: `set(1, 2)` is a `TypeError`.  Did you mean `set([1, 2])`, or `{1, 2}` instead?

Comment: I checked my if conditions, and I receive values like 0 and -83, so they should evaluate, ah and yes I did, let me edit that

Comment: I added more, but I don't understand enough to be able to provide something that can run. I hope you get the gist of what I'm doing, most of the other code isn't involved in this part, but maybe it's something with scoping or my version of python? I'm very stumped since it looks right to my untrained eye

Comment: Can't tell from the code you've posted, sorry. `s2 = down; print s2; print down` shouldn't be printing different things, regardless of scoping or Python versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `s1 = s2 = set()` instead of `= 0`.

As for your second question, there are probably better and more known ways to go around your problem. For example, using bit logic:

```
right = 1
up = 2
left = 4
down = 8

select = 0


if (small2x - smallx) < 0:  
    select |= right
if (small2x - smallx) >0:
    select |= left

if (small2y - smally) < 0:
    select |= down
if (small2y - smally) >0:
    select |= up

print(select)
print("You chose %s%s%s%s" %("UP " if select & up else "",
                             "DOWN " if select & down else "", 
                             "LEFT " if select & left else "",
                             "RIGHT" if select & right else ""))


#Do things after
```

Comment: Is the |= operator like a +=? Also, after making the `s1=s2=set()` edit, I end up with empty sets instead of 0, so it's a little closer but somehow still off the mark. I also gt the error `'set' object has no attribute 'intersect'`. Odd, maybe I'll stick to using & instead.

Comment: it's because it's not `intersect`, it's `intersection`. The `a |= b`, equal to `a = a | b` is a bitwise `or` operator; in this case, it'll set `a`'s bits to `1` if the respective bit in `b` is 1. For example `51 | 80` becomes `115` because `0110011 | 1010000 = 1110011`